# Extract ids from OpenStreetMap Overpass API output (python list in dictionary)

Tags: python, json, dictionary, openstreetmap, overpass-api

I'm querying OpenStreetMaps' Overpass Turbo API ([Link](https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/z4r)) with Python

```
import requests
import json

lat='51.404924'
lon='12.444895'

overpass_url = "http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter"
overpass_query = "[out:json][timeout:600];(way(around:700,"+lat+","+lon+")[landuse=industrial];);out geom;"

response = requests.get(overpass_url, 
                        params={'data': overpass_query})

data = response.json()
for key in data:
      print("dict has", key)

elements=data["elements"]
print(type(elements))
```

and getting this result (shortened):

```
{
  "version": 0.6,
  "generator": "Overpass API 0.7.55 579b1eec",
  "elements": [
    {
      "type": "way",
      "id": 12805981,
      "geometry": [
        {
          "lat": 51.410593,
          "lon": 12.4327856
        },
      ],
      "tags": {
        "addr:housenumber": "1",
        "addr:street": "BMW-Allee",
        "landuse": "industrial",
        "name": "BMW Werk 07.10 Leipzig",
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I get the **name** and **id**? I've thought, that dictionaries [can't contain lists](https://wiki.python.org/moin/DictionaryKeys), but here it does indeed. Because of this my initial idea

```
print(data["elements"]["tags"]["name"])
```

doesn't work.

Thanks for your help (this is my first question ;))

Answer (score 1):

```
print(data["elements"][0]["tags"]["name"])
print(data['elements'][0]['id'])
```

Index into the elements array.

Dictionaries cannot have lists for keys, but can have lists for values.

You can use a tuple as a key in a dictionary. Basically anything immutable can be a key in a dict.

Comment: Thanks for your help! May you also be so kind to help me implement reading the latitudes & longitudes from a csv file?

Comment: There are enough examples on the Internet how to read a file. CSV in particular is one of the easiest file formats.